# Best practice for creating many UIColors?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I have a table view with hundreds of custom drawn UITableViewCells which are drawn using the `drawRect:` method. These cells all share the same color styles. So, in each `drawRect:`, I do something like this:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.98 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1.0];
    /* use colors */
}
```

And so as you're scrolling down the table, this gets called hundreds of times. I'm not really sure if what I'm doing is efficient though. Is there a better way to create these colors, maybe with some reusability? Should I cache these colors in some global variable? Is what I am doing expensive or negligible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should profile with Instruments to see if a considerable amount of time is spent in these calls. If this is the case, then make them static variables and initialize them on first use:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    static UIColor *bgColor;
    static UIColor *textColor;
    static UIColor *strokeColor;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        bgColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0];
        textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.98 alpha:1.0];
        strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1.0];
    });

    /* use colors */
}
```

Comment: Even if I'm not spending that much time in those calls, shouldn't I do what you did above anyway? No doubt it would be more efficient anyway, no?

Comment: If it makes your programs faster then you should do it. If it makes no significant change to the performance of your program, then it is just a matter of taste. I would probably do it this way, others might not.

Comment: What was the final result? Does the initialization of the UIColor take time?

Comment: @Eric: You probably want to ask mohabitar about the result. In this case you should start the comment with "@mohabitar:" to make sure that he is notified.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to create these colors, maybe with some reusability?

your cell could hold a `MONSharedCellStuff` object, which can be created and set by the controller that creates the cell. an interface may take the form:

```
@interface MONSharedCellStuff : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) UIColor * bgColor;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) UIColor * textColor;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) UIColor * strokeColor;

@end
```

you can also use this instance for sharing other immutable things (common images or fonts).

alternatively, the cell could just create and hold these itself during initialization (although that would take more time and memory than proper sharing). that is fine for the simple cases.

with that many cells, it's important to reuse cells efficiently.

> Should I cache these colors in some global variable?

No. again, the controller that creates the cells may be a good place to cache and create them.

> Is what I am doing expensive or negligible?

Refer to the memory and CPU profilers.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.alexedge.co.uk/blog/2013/07/08/speeding-up-uicolor-categories/) on using UIColor categories for this purpose.